# How to properly use a vector range constructor?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, fstream, most-vexing-parse

I want to load all the lines from a text file into a `vector<string` by using its range constructor and then output them through `cout`:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<vector>
#include<iterator>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  ifstream file("file.txt");
  vector<string> strings(istream_iterator<string>(file) , istream_iterator<string>());

  for(auto s : strings)
    cout << s << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

When trying to compile the above code I get several errors, for instance:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘begin(std::vector<std::basic_string<char> > (&)    (std::istream_iterator<std::basic_string<char> >, std::istream_iterator<std::basic_string<char> > (*)    ()))’
   for(auto s : strings)
                ^
```

and several others...

I think I'm missing something obvious here, can anyone please help?

Comment: See the [Most Vexing Parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse).

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7007817/a-confusing-detail-about-the-most-vexing-parse

Comment: Got it. Should I delete this question or answer it myself?

Comment: Try declaring at least one of the iterators as a separate variable, that should remove the ambiguity. Man, that really sucks.

Comment: If you have a good answer, go for it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have fallen victim to the Most Vexing Parse, where the compiler sees your declaration as a function `strings` returning a `vector<string>`, taking two arguments:

- an `istream_iterator<string>` called `file`
- an unnamed pointer to function taking no arguments and returning a `istream_iterator<string>`.

To eliminate the vexing parse, use an extra pair of parentheses around the first argument:

```
vector<string> strings((istream_iterator<string>(file)) , istream_iterator<string>());
//                     ^                              ^
```

or, alternatively in C++11, use curly braces for the `strings` constructor

```
vector<string> strings{istream_iterator<string>(file) , istream_iterator<string>()};
//                    ^                                                           ^
```

**NOTE**: Clang warns you about it through `-Wvexing-parse` (on by default).