# Constructor interpreted as function call, and move constructors strangly skipped

Tags: c++, constructor, move-constructor, most-vexing-parse

I have a class with 4 constructors, and a function as below:

```
using namespace std;

class ABC {
public:
    ABC() {
        cout << "ABC()\n";
    }

    ABC(int) {
        cout << "ABC(int)\n";
    }

    ABC(ABC&) {
        cout << "ABC(&)\n";
    }

    ABC(ABC&&) {
        cout << "ABC(&&)\n";
    }
};


void ff(ABC t) { }
```

Please help me to explain some behaviours that seem strange to me (I use MSVC 2016 to compile):

1) Why do I get warning C4930: "'ABC a1(ABC (__cdecl *)(void))': prototyped function not called (was a variable definition intended?)" with the following code:

```
void main() {
    ABC a1(ABC());
    ff(ABC(5));
}
```

and on execution, I expect to get the following output:

```
ABC()
ABC(&&)
ABC(int)
ABC(&&)
```

but what I really get is

```
ABC(int)
```

2) Now if I change to

```
void main() {
    ABC a1(ABC(5));
    ff(ABC(5));
}
```

there is no more warning. But on execution, what I expect to get is

```
ABC(int)
ABC(&&)
ABC(int)
ABC(&&)
```

but what I really get is

```
ABC(int)
ABC(int)
```

3) Now

```
void main() {
    ABC( ABC() );
    ff(ABC(5));
}
```

It even doesn't compile. I get error C2660: "'ABC': function does not take 1 arguments".

4) Finally, why the following compiles while 3) doesn't?

```
void main() {
    ff(ABC(5));
}
```

Comment: part of the issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38951362/most-vexing-parse

Comment: Code snippet in 1 and 2 is exactly the same. And it must be `int main()` not `void`

Comment: Are you using C++11 or later?

Comment: Please fix the problem that the code "Now if I change to" is exactly the same as the previous code

Comment: Sorry, I have corrected the snippet 2.
Yes, I am using C++14.

Answer (score 5):

Due to the problem known as the [most vexing parse in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14077608/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-most-vexing-parse), the line

```
ABC a1(ABC());
```

declares `a1` to be a function whose return type is `ABC` and whose argument type is a function that takes no argument and returns `ABC`.

---

The line

```
ABC(ABC());
```

is a harder to dissect but it is also a declaration of a function, not the definition of a variable.

```
int(a);
```

is a valid declaration of the variable `a`. It is same as:

```
int a;
```

Similarly, the line with `ABC` is same as:

```
ABC ABC();
```

Here `ABC` has overloaded meaning. The first `ABC` is the type name. The second `ABC` is the function name (due to the most vexing parse). It declares `ABC` to be a function that takes no arguments and returns an object of type `ABC`. For the rest of the function, `ABC` is the function name, not the type name. Consequently,

```
ff(ABC(5));
```

is invalid since in that context `ABC` is a function that takes no arguments.

---

I don't have an answer to the question of why the move constructor does not get called.

Comment: second problem seems to be OP's mistakely used the same code as in 1. I guess it is `ABC a1(ABC(5));` instead

Comment: And seems OP asks why call to move ctor is missing.

Comment: I'm not positive, but I think the move constructors aren't called because the compiler has the option to exclude them for efficiency purposes.

Comment: @R Sahu: Thanks a lot for your explaination about MVP. But I am still waiting for answer for the move constructor to complete.