# Why constructors not called?

Tags: c++, c++11

In the following code, I have two parametrizes constructors. I have compiled and run into **Gcc** compiler but constructors not called.

```
#include <iostream>

class A 
{
  public:
  A(int i) 
  { 
      std::cout << "A constructed" << std::endl; 
  }
};

class B 
{
  public:
  B(A a1) 
  { 
      std::cout << "B constructed" << std::endl; 
  }
};

int main() 
{
  int i = 5;
  B b1(A(i));
  std::cout << i << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
5
```

So, Why constructors not called?

Comment: I assume the compiler optimises the construction of the objects away, since they are not used anymore afterwards.

Comment: Both constructor are actually `private`, so you cannot call then. According to clang (I would not have found it myself), you are facing the [Most vexing parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse) - `B b1(A(i))` is not constructing a variable `b1`, but declaring a function. The `i` that you use in `B b1(A(i))` is not the `i` you declared a line before (try removing it, the code will still compile).

Comment: @StoryTeller I do agree that these duplicates are (very closely) related, but I found the syntactic ambiguity here much more *vexing* than the ones in the provided links - I am well aware of the most vexing parse, but I would not have detected it here without clang's warning, maybe it is worth having a specific answer for this question (or maybe a canonical one elsewhere).

Comment: @Holt - I did answer a similar question once, wher `T(foo)` declared a parameter name `foo`. So this is still a dupe. I'm just looking

Comment: @StoryTeller Maybe this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38951362/most-vexing-parse (or the duplicate target).

Comment: @Holt - Edited both in. I don't think there's a facet of the most vexing parse that isn't covered by the linked dupes anymore.

Answer (score -4):

Your both constructors are defined under private. Private constructors are not visible to the objects and thus cannot be called.

Comment: That would cause an error. Not compile and run....