# Why I can't use pointer to a function

Tags: c++, function-pointers

There is an objects with field `double (A :: *ptrToFunc)();` Object `B` has got `A`; Can't use it in objects `B`.

```
class Foo
{
public:
    
    double (Foo :: *ptrToFunc)();
    
private:
    double func1();
    double func2();
    
public:
    Foo() : ptrToFunc{ &Foo::func1 } {}
}

class B
{
public:
    Foo obj();
    double countVal()
    {
        return (obj.*ptrToFunc)();  // use of undeclared identifier ptrToFunc
        return (obj.ptrToFunc)();  // called object (..) not a function or function pointer
    }
}

int main()
{
    B obj_B;
    double var = obj_B.countVal();
    return 0;
}
```

I have read [C++ Tutorial: Pointer-to-Member Function](https://www.codeguru.com/cplusplus/c-tutorial-pointer-to-member-function/) but it doesn't help me.

Comment: please review your code formatting. And please ask a quesiton. And please explain what "I cant" means. WHen your code has errors, include the compiler error message in the quesiton

Comment: `Foo obj()` is vexing parse. It declares a `obj` as a member function.

Comment: you want to get the pointer `obj.ptrToFunc` (that's where the pointer is stored) and then use that pointer on `obj` again? Hint: you'd write `obj` twice

Comment: `Foo obj();` is declaring a method named `obj` that has no parameters and returns `Foo`. I doubt this is what you meant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are *2 problems* with your code.

##### Problem 1

`Foo obj();` is a member function declaration and not a data member declaration because of *vexing parse* (note the absence of "most"). That is, `Foo obj();` declares a member function named `obj` with no parameter and return type `Foo`.

To **solve** this, replace it with:

```
//-----vv--->use braces
Foo obj{};
```

---

##### Problem 2

The second problem is that the syntax `return (obj.*ptrToFunc)();` is incorrect as `obj.ptrToFunc` refers to the pointer and we still need to use that pointer on an object (as shown below).

To **solve** this 2nd problem, replace it with:

```
(obj.*(obj.ptrToFunc))() // or same as (obj.*obj.ptrToFunc)()
```

[Working demo](https://godbolt.org/z/szdzbbrfz)

---

With [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17), you can make the code more readable by using `std::invoke`:

```
double countVal()
{
//--------------vvvvvv--------------------->use invoke
    return std::invoke(obj.ptrToFunc, obj); 
}
```

[Demo c++17](https://godbolt.org/z/1E5az4TfE)

Comment: `obj.*obj.ptrToFunc` looks pretty weird. I'd add more parens: `obj.*(obj.ptrToFunc)`

Comment: about Foo obj(); my bad; i didn't mean obj is a method, don't copy/paste my classes because there are quite big, i was trying to write a small example

Comment: @VadimShestak It's ok, also refer to [most vexing parse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38951362/most-vexing-parse).

Comment: To make the (not very frequently used, in the wild) invocation a little gentler on the eyes: `auto func{ obj.ptrToFunc }; return (obj.*func)();`

Comment: @Eljay Yeah, `auto` can be used here to make the code more readable(?).

Comment: On modern C++ the problem 2 can be solved in a quite readable way by using `std::invoke(obj.Foo::ptrToFunc, obj)`

Answer (score 0):

Another slightly different way to solve the issues pointed out by the accepted answer. I rather like std::invoke from 'functional' than can call whatever is callable without too much trouble.

Also made the code self contained to make it easy to try it for future readers.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional> class Foo { public:
    
    double (Foo::*ptrToFunc)();
     private:
    double func1() { return 1.0;}
    double func2() { return 2.0;}
     public:
    Foo() : ptrToFunc{&Foo::func2} {} };

class B { public:
    Foo obj = Foo();
    double countVal()
    {
        return std::invoke(obj.Foo::ptrToFunc, obj);       
    } };

int main() {
    B obj_B;
    double var = obj_B.countVal();
    std::cout << var << std::endl;
    return 0; }
```