# Can't read whole file into string

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    ifstream file;

    do {
        string filename;
        cout << "Input file name:" << endl;
        cin >> filename;
        file.open(filename, ios::in);
    } while (!file.is_open());

    string content(istreambuf_iterator<char>(file),
                   istreambuf_iterator<char>());

    cout << "Content:\n" << content << endl;

    if (file.is_open()) {
        file.close();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

To read this file content:

```
 1 -1  0 -3  0
-2  5  0  0  0
 0  0  4  6  4
-4  0  2  7  0
 0  8  0  0 -5
```

But it outputs `1` only and a new line.
P.S. I am a nobie and just learn C++ by samples. What do I doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you reading integral values into a `string`?  Wouldn't it make more sense to read integer values into an integer container?

Comment: No, I want to read it into the `string` as simple lines. As I wrote it is for learning only.

Comment: First, what is in that file?  Are those the actual **characters** in the file, or does the file consist of integers that happen to have those values?  It makes a big difference as to what is actually in the file.

Comment: Just I copied a file content to here. It uses UTF-8 encoding but as I know codes of numbers are same like in the ASCII standard.

Comment: @NeilButterworth, I have problems with a console encoding so it outputs me a some bred instead of normal warnings.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Wow, that was a sneaky one!

Compiling your code on [Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6a9f24ac6df4eca0) produced this warning:

```
main.cpp:20:29: warning: the address of 'std::__cxx11::string content(std::istreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> >, std::istreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> > (*)())' will always evaluate as 'true' [-Waddress]
```

Address? What address?? Well, if you look closely at this parenthesized mess and squint a lot, you'll eventually notice that:

```
string content(istreambuf_iterator<char>(file),
               istreambuf_iterator<char>());
```

... is actually... a function declaration! Specifically, a function named `content`, taking two parameters of type `std::istreambuf_iterator<char>` and returning an `std::string`.
And indeed, `std::cout << content;` takes the address of this function and converts it to a boolean, yielding `1` and a fair warning.

This problem is known as the "most vexing parse". It is one of the reasons to use uniform initialization, as folows:

```
string content{istreambuf_iterator<char>{file},
               istreambuf_iterator<char>{}};
```

No more syntactic ambiguity, `content` is now an actual `std::string`, and everything works.

But do take a moment to [unlearn `using namespace std;`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice). Thanks :)

Comment: Thank you for detail explanation. I can get that `{}` allows to get a compiler that it's variable. But I can't get why this `string content((istreambuf_iterator<char>(file)),
                   istreambuf_iterator<char>());` works but mine does not? Can you explain yet just a bit, please?

Comment: I.e. why `(istreambuf_iterator<char>(file))` doesn't equal `istreambuf_iterator<char>(file)`?

Comment: @Шах There's no meaning to the parentheses (`foo` is still semantically equivalent to `(foo)`), their only use is to make sure that the *syntax* cannot be a function declaration. This is because such an ambiguous line is defined to be parsed, if possible, as a function declaration first.

Comment: Sorry for my poor English... I.e. `int foo(1);` can be interpretated as a function but `int foo((1));` is like a variable in the body of a some function?

Comment: @Шах that's the spirit. In your case `int foo(1);` cannot be a function declaration though. The ambiguity arises when there's a type: is `int foo(float(bar));` an `int` initialized with `float(bar)` (`bar` cast to `float`), or a function signature for `int foo(float bar);`? You can wrap a parameter's name in parentheses when declaring it, so it could be both. Hence, the function is chosen. You can't, however, wrap the *whole* parameter, so `int foo((float(bar)));` cannot be a function: it's unambiguously an `int`.

Comment: I don't sure that I understood correct and feel self stupid... But seems I got u. Thank you very much!

Comment: [Most vexing parse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7007817/a-confusing-detail-about-the-most-vexing-parse)

Comment: Thanks for a link! I didn't know about it. Now I understood my mistake.

Comment: @Шах don't worry, that's just one of the weird corners of C++. Most programmers bump into it sometimes, and they just curse a bit, add some parentheses or braces and move along :)

Comment: Yeah, it is mush harder than C# or Java. But at least I understood this error.