# Can't write to ostream in gnu linux c++ error: invalid operands of types ofstream and ‘const char [2]’ to binary ‘operator

Tags: c++, linux, c++11, fstream

Can't compile this small code on Linux:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    char fileName[512];
    sprintf(fileName, "test");
    ofstream iriFile(string(fileName));
    iriFile<<",";
    return 0;
}
```

I am compiling like this: **g++ test.cpp** and am getting this:

> test.cpp:12:11: error: invalid operands of types
>   ‘std::ofstream(std::__cxx11::string) {aka
>   std::basic_ofstream(std::__cxx11::basic_string)}’ and
>   ‘const char [2]’ to binary ‘operator<<’   iriFile<<",";

What might be the reason?

Comment: `ofstream iriFile(string(fileName));` is a function declaration, see Most Vexing Parse. No time to look for the best dupe now, but in general, the compiler can warn you about that. https://wandbox.org/permlink/tgimOpyhXGcD1Spu

Comment: Very related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7007817/a-confusing-detail-about-the-most-vexing-parse

Comment: That's a lot of wheel-spinning; just say `ofstream iriFile("test");`

Comment: There are quite a few posts in SO on the topic of the most vexing parse. See https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcpp%5D+most+vexing+parse. The crux of the problem is that `ofstream iriFile(string(fileName));` is parsed as `ofstream iriFile(string fileName);`, which is just a function declaration.

Comment: It's often worth testing with both GCC and Clang if you can't figure an error out: *warning: parentheses were disambiguated as a function declaration [-Wvexing-parse]*

Comment: Change `ofstream iriFile(string(fileName));` to `ofstream iriFile{string(fileName)};`, to avoid the Most Vexing Parse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, the solution is to remove implicit string() creation:

```
string sFileName(fileName)
ofstream iriFile(sFileName);
```

Comment: I think you meant "explicit" string creation.

Comment: Just pass it as it is without your pesky conversions that is not necessary, and if you want to play safe use C++ cast, not C

Answer (score 1):

First of all you do not need to explicitly convert `const char *` to `std::string` there is `std::ifstream` constructor for it:

```
 std::ofstream iriFile(fileName);
```

but if you want to be extra safe and verbose use proper C++ then:

```
std::ofstream iriFile( static_cast<std::string>(fileName) );
```

not C style cast.

Answer (score 0):

As you pointed out, removing the explicit string creation fixes it.

It could be worth to add that this can also be fixed for types with `explicit` constructors by using [`list initialization`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization), like so:

```
ofstream iriFile(string{sFileName});
```

Comment: It's because im not a native english speaker and words like `explicit` and `implicit` confuse me a little. So I just copied the word because I thought thats what I wanted to say. I'll correct it.