# Understanding void func(A())

Tags: c++

This is my code

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class A {
public:
    int a = 0;
    A(int i = 0) : a(i) {}
};

void func(A())
{
    std::cout << "Hello" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    A(*p)() = NULL;
    func(p);
}
```

What confused me is that `A()` in `void func(A())` is equal to A`(*)()` instead of `A`'s constructor. How does this work?

Comment: what would it mean when `A()` was `A`'s constructor?

Comment: Anything that can be parsed as a function declaration is a function declaration.  Look up _"most vexing parse"_.  Can't find a canonical duplicate but lots of similar.

Comment: @Richard [Most Vexing Parse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7007817/a-confusing-detail-about-the-most-vexing-parse)

Comment: @Adrian-ReinstateMonica Thanks, I found that one - as this Q is so common was hoping for higher votes.

Comment: @RichardCritten I’m not sure this is related to the Most Vexing Parse, as this is specifically in the context of a function declaration where other parses couldn’t (?) apply. But perhaps I’m mistaken?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let’s reason by analogy. If you define a function

```
void doSomething(A [137]) {

}
```

then C++ treats it as though you’d actually written

```
void doSomething(A *) {

}
```

In other words, there are some types where, if you use them as a parameter to a function, C++ will automatically replace them with a different type, the type you’d get by *decaying* the type.

In your case, `A()` is the type of a function that takes in no arguments and returns an `A`. If you have a C++ function that takes an `A()` as an argument, C++ will instead have the function take as input an `A (*)()`, a pointer to a function taking no arguments and returning an `A`. The reason for this is that you can’t have an object of type `A()` in C++, though you can have a pointer to an `A()`.