# why is `std::istreambuf_iterator<char>` regard as function declaration when constrcuting a string?

Tags: c++, parameters, expression, ambiguity, function-declaration

Many coders may be confused this code:

```cpp
int main() {
  std::ifstream ifs("filename", std::ios::binary);
  std::string content((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(ifs)), std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());
  //                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
  ...
}
```

I would like to understand this code clearly, so the question is:

1. Why is `std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(ifs)` enclosed in `(`, `)`?
2. How to determinate this code if remove the brackets here? and
3. How to determinate the code if we don't remove the brackets?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A confusing detail about the Most Vexing Parse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7007817/a-confusing-detail-about-the-most-vexing-parse)

Comment: @Kaldrr thx, but what I want to understand is about Internal mechanism. By the way, what's meaning of function declaration in a function block?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In declarations declarators may be enclosed in parentheses.

Consider the following function declaration

```
void f( int ( x ), int ( y ) );
```

This declaration declares a function with two parameters of the type int.

In a declaration names of identifiers may be omitted.

So you may write

```
void f( int (), int () );
```

This declaration in turn declares a function that accepts two parameters of the function type `int()`.

So this construction

```
std::string content(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(ifs), std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());
```

can be considered by the compiler as a declaration of a function that has the return type std::string and with the first parameter of the type `std::istreambuf_iterator<char>` and the identifier `ifs` and the second parameter with the  function type `istreambuf_iterator<char>()`.

To distinguish a declaration from an expression there are used either parentheses like

```
std::string content( ( std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(ifs) ), std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());
```

or braces

```
std::string content(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>{ ifs }, std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());
```

Here is a demonstration program that shows how can look declarators in parameter declarations.

```
#include <iostream>

void f( int ( x ), int ( y ) )
{
    std::cout << "x = " << x << ", y = " << y << '\n';
}

void f( int(), int() );

void f( int g(), int h() )
{
    std::cout << g() + h() << '\n';
}    

int g() { return 100; }

int main()
{
    f( 10, 20 );    

    f( g, g );
}
```

The program output is

```
x = 10, y = 20
200
```

As for the question appeared in a comment about declaration of a parameter of a function type then for example the C function `qsort` uses such a parameter that specifiers the relation between two elements of an array.

```
void qsort(void *base, size_t nmemb, size_t size,
int compar(const void *, const void *));
```

Another example is of using a function type as a template argument for a class template `std::function`.

Comment: Thx, its easily to understand, but what's meaning of function declaration in a function block? Why does compiler treat it as a function declaration instead of a variable? Is there any useful place to declare a function in a function?

Comment: @GallenCalade As I mentioned the identifiers of declarators may be omitted if they are not used. So a function parameter that has a function type like for example int h() can be written like int() omitting the identifier h. Function types are very often used for example as template arguments of std::function.