# Most Vexing Parse: why do the extra parentheses work?

Tags: c++, most-vexing-parse

In order to avoid the Most Vexing Parse I added extra parentheses here:

```
std::vector<int> v(std::istream_iterator<int>(inp), (std::istream_iterator<int>()));
```

Where `inp` is an `istringstream` created from a `std::string`.

But why do the extra parentheses work?  Why doesn't the compiler ignore them as redundant?

Comment: Because it's not a valid way to declare a function.  Function declaration syntax is not an "operation" where parenthesis mean order of operation.   It's syntactically invalid to have them in that position of a function declaration.  So then it must be a function call and only after that's determined are they processed and essentially discarded.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A confusing detail about the Most Vexing Parse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7007817/a-confusing-detail-about-the-most-vexing-parse)

Comment: With regards to the duplicate target, read this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23726218/4342498