# Vector constructor identified as function

Tags: c++, constructor

Consider this piece of code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
    
int main() {
    std::istringstream ss("abcabc abc a b e");
    std::vector<std::string> words(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(ss), std::istream_iterator<std::string>());
    std::string deciphered;
    int shift = 5;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < shift; i++)
    {
        for (size_t j = 0; i + j < words.size(); j += shift)
        {
            deciphered += words[i + j];
        }
    }
}
```

Basically, I want to split words and store them to my `words` array. But I get compile errors:

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:14:40: error: request for member 'size' in 'words', which is of non-class type 'std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >(std::istream_iterator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >, std::istream_iterator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > (*)())'
   14 |       for (size_t j = 0; i + j < words.size(); j += shift)
      |                                        ^~~~
main.cpp:16:33: warning: pointer to a function used in arithmetic [-Wpointer-arith]
   16 |        deciphered += words[i + j];
      |                                 ^
main.cpp:16:33: error: invalid conversion from 'std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > (*)(std::istream_iterator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >, std::istream_iterator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > (*)())' to 'char' [-fpermissive]
   16 |        deciphered += words[i + j];
      |                      ~~~~~~~~~~~^
      |                                 |
      |                                 std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > (*)(std::istream_iterator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >, std::istream_iterator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > (*)())
In file included from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\string:55,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\bits\locale_classes.h:40,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\bits\ios_base.h:41,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\ios:42,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\ostream:38,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\iostream:39,
                 from main.cpp:1:
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\bits\basic_string.h:1186:25: note:   initializing argument 1 of 'std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>& std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::operator+=(_CharT) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; _Alloc = std::allocator<char>]'
 1186 |       operator+=(_CharT __c)
      |                  ~~~~~~~^~~
```

Judging by the errors, my variable `words` was identified as a function.

I'm so confused, what's the reason for this behavior? And how do I fix it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A confusing detail about the Most Vexing Parse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7007817/a-confusing-detail-about-the-most-vexing-parse)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what is known as [most vexing parse](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/most-vexing-parse/info), in this case you should use the braced initialization syntax which will let the compiler know you are trying to construct an instance of a class instead of declaring a function.

i.e `std::vector<int> a{}` instead of `std::vector<int> a()`

Answer (score 1):

According to the rules of the C++ language, in this line:

```
std::vector<std::string> words(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(ss), std::istream_iterator<std::string>());
```

It is a declaration of a new identifier `words`, as you intended.  However, everything else goes unintended:

`words` is a function, returning `std::vector<std::string>` and taking two parameters both of type `std::istream_iterator<std::string>`.  The first parameter is named `ss` and the second parameter is unnamed.

Throughout multiple C++ versions, there have been a variety of ways to force the compiler to see this as the declaration and initialization of a variable.  The easiest one, added in C++11, is what @Moshe suggested: Use braces not parenthesis to designate the initializers.

```
std::vector<std::string> words{std::istream_iterator<std::string>(ss), std::istream_iterator<std::string>()};
```