# This std::pair constructor does not compile

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, std, std-pair

Minimal example:

```
#include <utility>

struct A {
    A(int x) {}
};

int main() {
    int x = 3, y = 3;
    //std::pair<A, A> pa(A(3), A(3));
    //std::pair<A, A> pa(A(x), A(y));
    //std::pair<A, A> pa((A(x)), A(x));

    std::pair<A, A> pa(A(x), A(x));
}
```

Why does this C++ code snippet not compile? I tried various compilers on Godbolt, and the compiler errors/warnings look something like this:

```
<source>:10:29: error: redefinition of parameter 'x'
        std::pair<A, A> pa(A(x), A(x));
                                   ^
<source>:10:23: note: previous declaration is here
        std::pair<A, A> pa(A(x), A(x));
                             ^
<source>:10:20: warning: parentheses were disambiguated as a function declaration [-Wvexing-parse]
        std::pair<A, A> pa(A(x), A(x));
```

The commented out lines are examples of "fixes" to make it work as expected: I wish to create a new pair of constructed As. I can do it out of constants, but I can't do it out of variables with the same value as the constant! The parser breaks.

It's like it's interpreting that line as:

```
std::pair<A, A> pa(A x, A x);
```

, which I don't understand.

Can anyone explain what's going on here?

Comment: I think this question should be reopened, the associated post does not answer my question at all.

Comment: Actually it does :-/. Just replace your definition by `std::pair<A, A> pa{A{x}, A{x}};` and it should work. In general, in most cases I'd advise to use the [uniform initialization syntax](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/cpp11-language#uniform-init).

Comment: I found in this thread that my parantheses are simply getting ignored, and that is normal: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7007817/a-confusing-detail-about-the-most-vexing-parse

Comment: @LeonardInkret that link doesn't state that the parenthesis are ignored - it states that they are superfluous in this context.  They are order-of-evaluation parenthesis.